# How to I hide menu items based on its access to different roles?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I have a site with the following users

1. Administrator
2. Author
3. Normal user(authenticated user)

and the modules used for the following task are [Nice Menu](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus), [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) and [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print).

The site contains of books and the option shown for every book page is shown in fig.

[image]

1. Administrator and Authors will have access to every option.
2. Authenticated user is not able to Edit Page and access the Page History.

By configuring the [print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module and using [tokens](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) I have accomplished the task, but it shows an "Access Denied" error when an authenticated user tries to select that option.

Is there a way to hide the "Edit Page" and "Page History" option for authenticated user and keep it visible to Admin and Authors?

Thank you in advance,
Ajit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this with the [Menu Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module.

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items1 based on user roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears in the node edit form.